# Why are there two ones on these lines? Is it a typo?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

I'm reading "Classic Set Theory: For Guided Independent Study" and at page 192 it gives an example (no need to read it all):

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's a typo but since it's a double one I will ask for confirmation, shouldn't the first $1$ on those lines be $0$ (corresponding to $n=0$, in this book $0\in\mathbb{N}$)?

Comment: Seems so. ${}{}$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin yeah seems obvious, thank you

Comment: Yes, you are right, actually the first $1$ have to be $0$.